# Phalcon PhP - how to change the view dynamically

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm working in a website where part of it I have the static html, so I created a layout and in it I'm inserting the static content using views. My problem is as this website has many pages I feel wrong creating an action for each url. So I implemented the controller below:

```
class PageController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function initialize(){
        $this->init();
        $this->view->setLayout( 'website' );
    }

    public function indexAction ($url=''){
        if($url == 'about')
            $this->view->pick('page/about');
    }
}
```

When I set the controller view to render $this->view->pick('page/about'); it doesn't insert the view in the template. It renders only the view.

Is there a way to render the view within the layout, and is there a better approach to what I'm doing?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a template you should use

```
$this->view->setTemplateAfter('website');
```

instead of `$this->view->setLayout( 'website' );`

By using `$this->view->pick('page/about');` you are overwriting the layout set by `$this->view->setLayout( 'website' );`, resulting in only seeing the `page/about` layout.