# Phalcon PhP - set view dynamically

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm working on a website with Phalcon PhP and I would like to set the view (.volt file) dynamically, based on the url.

Currently, I can get the url and the url matches the name of the .volt file. My problem is that I can get the content of the .volt file but the layout seems to be blank because the page renders without any style. My stylesheets I include in the layout.

Here is the code of my action:

```
   public function indexAction($url){
        $this->view->setLayout( 'website' );
        $this->view->pick('program/'.$url);
   }
```

The url comes right, I render the .volt content but the layout seems to be blank.

Currently I do something very similar in another session and the layout works:

```
$html = $this->view->getRender('page', $url,
    array('page_title' => $page_title,
        'page_css_class' => $page_css_class)
);
die($html);
```

But for this feature, I want to do different because I also have to set a bunch of other stuff dynamically, such as `$this->assets->addJs('x.js');` etc...

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What's your Phalcon version? Also have you used `website` layout before, was it working?

Comment: The version is 2.0. Yes, I use this template in other pages and I do something very similar to what I'm trying to do ( I will add to the question).

Comment: Didn't you ask this a time ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044087/phalcon-php-how-to-change-the-view-dynamically/39044344

Comment: @AndréLuiz Do you need to have your html code in a variable or just display it on your website?

Comment: @AndréLuiz you accepted Timothy's answer back in Aug but never used his code?

Comment: no, these seem like two different issues. at the time, no style was claimed to be rendered, as in now it seems it's a part of the page that's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just make "pick" parameter array:

```
$this->view->pick(['program/'.$url]);
```

Thats it. Remove set layout function, u dont need it (if website is default layout). 
This is not showed in documentation in best way, but you can check githube zaphir code for details [here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/view.zep).

Good luck :)